# How to change values for any number of cells with one spin button?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

There are any number of cells containing formulas like
`=SUM(A1;A2)`,..., `=SUM(N1;N2)`.

Now I want one spin button which changes all formulas at once into `=Sum(A1;A2;A3)`,...,`=SUM(N1;N2;N3)`.

There are 12 different forumlas for each cell.

"Of course" my formulas are quite more complex which is why the solution should be
as abstract as possible and not be taylored to solve exactly this sum-forumla-problem...

Maybe this is possible via a combination of spin button and dropdown lists containing my different formulas? I have no clue of Excel :(

How is this done? (I don't know VBA unfortunately)

Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: It would be pretty tough to do if the logic is different in each formula.  If they are all the same you can loop through cells and find the matching formula then alter it.  Would be really slow if you have to loop through all cells.

Comment: So, to understand, will you always just add the next row to your range with each `up` selection (EG `XX1, XX2` becomes `XX1, XX2, XX3`... Not, for example `XX1, XX2, XX9`)? If so, I think this can be done...

Comment: 1. formula: `VLOOKUP(D10;#BEZUG!;3;WRONG)`

2. formula: `VLOOKUP(D10;#BEZUG!;3;WRONG)+VLOOKUP(D10;#BEZUG!;4;WRONG)`

3. etc. ... it is always +one more VLOOKUP, #Bezug! is always the same expression. The logic is always the same :)

Comment: sry. #Bezug! is altering like: VL(..A1) + VL(..A2) + VL(..A3) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your ranges are likely in sequence then you can use the following Function in VBA Editor and save the file as Excel Macro Enabled Workbook in Office-2007-onward versions:

```
Function AutoRange(rngFrom As Range, rngTo As Integer)
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim r As Range
    Dim cell1, cell2, Rng As Range

    Set cell1 = Cells(rngFrom.Row, rngFrom.Column)
    Set cell2 = Cells(rngFrom.Row + rngTo - 1, rngFrom.Column)
    Set Rng = Range(cell1, cell2)

        For Each r In Rng
            a = a + r
        Next
    AutoRange = a
End Function
```

The function can be used in the format given in following image, i just used 4 cells range here:

[image]

You just have to change green specified Cell value i.e. how much cells are in your Range in sequence downward. If it does not recalculate on changing green cell's value, just press Ctrl+Alt+F9. Just try it, thanks...